# Angular Radio Button not checked on page load/click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am having trouble with a radio button in angular. When the page loads I click on the radio and I want it to be selected with the current employee's team.

I am having trouble with a radio button in angular. When the page *loads*/ I click the radio I want it to be selected with the current employee's team. Right now it does not select at all unless you press it twice. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

I am writing a feature where there is a button dropdown menu with a list of teams. As an employee I can belong to one team only. When I click the button dropdown I want to see the radio button selected that is next to the team I belong to. I won't know for sure how many teams there will be, so I'm not able to hard code it. I've tried different things with `ngValue`, `ngChecked`, `ngInit` with no success.

This code snippet is inside of a ngRepeat for employee in employees.
    html code is here: http://jsbin.com/wasihecave/edit?html

```
employee.team is an id (ex: "1a2b3c4d")
team.id would be the same (ex: "1a2b3c4d")
employee.profile_uid is an id in the same format but a different id.
```

Comment: Have you tried using ngClick?

Comment: Hi Archie, Yes I have tried ngClick as well. Sadly that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you add your `controller` code.